# /usr/bin/rename: Argument list too long

Tags: command-line, bash, rename, batch-rename

I'm trying to rename a bunch of **files** and **folders**.

I tried this command `rename 's/test/test2/'` but I got `unable to execute /usr/bin/rename: Argument list too long`

I searched a lot and tried different solutions but I'm not getting it.

The last one I tried was this one `find . -type f -exec rename -n 's/test/test2/' ** {} \;` which I also got the same error.

Thank you!

Edit: Also tried `xargs -0 rename -n 's/test/test2/' **` and I got `xargs: cannot fit single argument within argument list size limit`

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
find . -type f -exec rename -n 's/test/test2/' {} +
```

The `-exec ... +` form will put as many arguments *as can fit*, so it will invoke `rename` as few times as possible.

Your mistake was using `find ... -exec` and *also* putting `**` on rename's argument list.

Comment: It works with the -n argument but if I take it out I got `unable to execute /usr/bin/rename: Argument list too long` however it lists all the files and folder it was supposed to change but saying `No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you have a file with an extremely long file name.

To find the top 5 longest file names in a given directory, use the following (replacing `/etc` with the path in question)

`ls /etc | perl -e 'print sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } <>' | head -5`

If you do have a filename that is absurdly long, you may be able to first rename it using the 'mv' command to a shorter name.

Comment: Maybe I have but I can't change it cause it would involve changing a lot of inner code.